# Resource Data Doesnt Write to TextFile

Tags: c++, resources

```
void Extract(WORD wResId , LPSTR lpszOutputPath)
{ 
    HRSRC hrsrc = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(wResId) , RT_RCDATA);
    HGLOBAL hLoaded = LoadResource( NULL,hrsrc);
    LPVOID lpLock =  LockResource( hLoaded);
    DWORD dwSize = SizeofResource(NULL, hrsrc);
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("C://Windows//Darek//mylo.txt",GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
    DWORD dwByteWritten;
    char* cRes = (char*)malloc (dwSize);
    memset(cRes,0,dwSize);
    memcpy (cRes, cData, dwSize);
    cRes[dwSize] = '\0';
    FreeResource(hLoaded);
    WriteFile(hFile, lpLock , dwSize , &dwByteWritten , NULL);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    FreeResource(hLoaded);
}
```

Ok this creates the file correctly, but the extracted data doesnt seem to extract and write to the textFile,Any problems? i do not seem to understand why it doesnt extract and Write the data to the file.

Please Help.

Comment: at least `cRes[dwSize] = '\0';` is invalid, you did not allocate enough memory to do that. But exactly what does not work? is nothing written to the file? What should be written to the file, and what is written to the file?

Comment: I'm trying to copy the byte of data from a dll and write to a file (textfile) to see how it first works before retrying with a dll again

Comment: and nothing is written to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating a memory block that is as large as the resource, zeroing it out (which is redundant), and copying something (what is `cData` pointing at? Maybe you meant `lpLock` instead?) into that memory, but then you are *ignoring* the allocated memory and leaking it.  You are trying to write the content of `lpLock` to the file as-is, which is what you should be doing, but you are not doing any error handling at all.  Chances are, your resource is missing, or otherwise not available for reading.  That would account for your file being empty.

Try this instead:

```
void Extract(WORD wResId, LPSTR lpszOutputPath)
{ 
    HRSRC hrsrc = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(wResId), RT_RCDATA);
    if (!hrsrc)
    {
        // GetLastError() tells you why it failed...
        return;
    }

    HGLOBAL hLoaded = LoadResource(NULL, hrsrc);
    if (!hLoaded)
    {
        // GetLastError() tells you why it failed...
        return;
    }

    DWORD dwSize = SizeofResource(NULL, hrsrc);
    if ((dwSize == 0) && (GetLastError() != 0))
    {
        // GetLastError() tells you why it failed...
        return;
    }

    LPVOID lpLock = LockResource(hLoaded);
    if (!lpLock)
    {
        // GetLastError() tells you why it failed...
        return;
    }

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(lpszOutputPath, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        // GetLastError() tells you why it failed...
        return;
    }

    DWORD dwByteWritten;
    if (!WriteFile(hFile, lpLock, dwSize, &dwByteWritten, NULL))
    {
        // GetLastError() tells you why it failed...
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        DeleteFileA(lpszOutputPath);
        return;
    }

    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

If I had to guess (and please don't make people guess), `FindResource()` is most likely returning `NULL`.  Make sure the second parameter actually matches the correct resource type for `wResId`.  You cannot load any arbitrary resource using `RT_RCDATA`, you have to use the correct resource type.  Only resources using the `RCDATA` type can be accessed using the `RT_RCDATA` parameter value.  String resources might be stored using the `RT_MESSAGETABLE` or `RT_STRING` type instead, for instance.  You can use `EnumResourceTypes()` and `EnumResourceNames()`, or an external resource editor/viewer tool, to find out what type the `wResId` resource is actually using.